# Working with mongoose and Mongo DB schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

We are working with mongoose in order to interact with Mongo DB.
We define the schema at the code level.
Now we want to move and use Mongo DB schema (**At the collection level inside DB**) and we dont want to maintain two types of schemas.
We wish to keep on working with mongoose because it comes with few nice features that we like.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean don't want to follow mongoose schema? if yes then you can declare schema/model without specifying properties `new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false, collection: "collection name" });`

Comment: I mean that I want to use Mongo DB schema. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/specify-json-schema/#std-label-schema-validation-json and not to maintain the mongose schema anymore.

Comment: "Any idea" means an npm package that generates jsonschema from mongoose schema, doesn't it? You've been here long enough to learn such questions are off-topic. Besides, google gives the answer much quicker.

Comment: Hi Alex. I don't need a tool that will translate mongoose to Mongo schema. I am looking for a way to get the benefits of mogoose ( like default value) with out double maintenance of schemas. I did a **deep** google search but found nothing.. So I came here to try and find a direction.

Comment: Fair enough. Look how mongoose works - indexes defined in mongoose schema are translated to mongodb index definitions, then you apply them to collections. There are number of attempts to translate mongoose schema to mongodb json schema, then again you apply them to collections. At some point you need whole json schema to pass to mongo on the wire, so I doubt there is any other possible approach. Speaking about quality of these implementations.... well it's very opinion based, and hopefully time sensitive if maintainers do their job, so I'll keep my opinion to myself.